# Show Out Of Stock text in Magento

Tags: magento, model-view-controller, configurable-product

I need to add on my dropdown list an style into thee out of stock text, im already using this:

```
if (count($productsIndex) == 1) {
                        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                            ->loadByProduct($productsIndex[0]);
                        if ($stockItem->getQty() == 0) {
                            $value['text'] .= ' Out Of Stock';
                        }
                    }
                    $info['options'][] = array(
                        'id'        => $value['value_index'],
                        'label'     => $value['label'],
                        'price'     => $configurablePrice,
                        'oldPrice'  => $this->_prepareOldPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                        'products'  => $productsIndex,
                    );
```

But this will show
12 Out Of Stock
This will display next to the size, how can i give style to this ?

Comment: you should consider not to mix code logic and templates/styles.

It looks like you are trying to modify getJsonConfig in
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable. 

Provide more context of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I did not do that...i was using json to send the data...